# Cannot figure out the output in this C program for calculation of sum and average using functions

Tags: c

I use Dev-C++ (MinGW Compiler) on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. I have written a simple program to find the sum and average of 5 integers (assuming average will be an int). Here is the code:

```
/*Sum and average of 5 integers*/
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a,b,c,d,e,sm,av;
    printf ("Enter any 5 integers:\n");
    scanf ("%d%d%d%d%d", &a,&b,&c,&d,&e);
    sumavg(a,b,c,d,e);
    printf ("\nSum = %d", sm);
    printf ("\nAverage = %d", av);
    getch();
}

sumavg(n,w,o,b,h)
{
     int sm = n+w+o+b+h;
     int av = sm/5;
     return(sm,av);
}
```

For some strange reason, the output is Sum = 2 and Average = 27, no matter what are the values of the 5 integers. Even if the average is not accurate (because it will be floating point ideally), at least the value of the sum returned should be accurate. What am I doing wrong? Thanks...

Comment: What magic will put a value into `sm` ? Not speaking of some other nonsensical constructs...Please grab a modern C book and read it.

Comment: `return(sm,av);` does not return 2 values, it returns av

Comment: The `av` in `main` is not the same `av` as in `sumavg` which is forgotten on function exit. Function `sumavg` attempts to return a value: which relies on out of date assumptions, and the value is not collected by `main` anyway.

Comment: `main()`? I'm sorry, are you from the past?

Comment: Do not write K&R (pre-standard) C functions.  Always use the modern (as in, for the last 28 years) notation with explicit types and full function prototypes.  (@Geoff: `main()` is less of a problem than `sumavg()`.)

Comment: That's not valid C! Pay heed to compiler warnings!

Comment: **main()? I'm sorry, are you from the past?**

Geoff, yes, actually I am from the past...picked up programming very late in life, so considering that C is a very old language and that writing the main function just as main() (just because I want to get down the basics correctly first), does make me look like i come from the past

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call a function in which you declare, and then give `sm` and `av` a value. But these variables are local variables, they have nothing to do with the ones that are in `main()`. If you declare a variable in a function and then you declare an other variable in an other function, these two variables are *not* the same, in any case, even if they have the same name. It's like people: you may have the same name than someone else, it doesn't mean that you are the same person, and it is definitely not.

To use the variables you declared in `main`, you could pass a pointer to them as argument of your function. Here is the prototype you would have:

```
void    sumavg(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int *sum, int *av)
```

You could also use 2 different functions that calculates the sum or average of all your ints, and then return the result directly into the variables of your `main`:

```
int    main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, d, e, sm, av;

    printf ("Enter any 5 integers:\n");
    scanf ("%d%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);
    sm = get_sm(a, b, c, d, e);
    av = get_av(a, b, c, d, e);
    printf ("\nSum = %d", sm);
    printf ("\nAverage = %d", av);
    return (0);
}
```

For example:

```
int    get_sum(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
    return (a + b + c + d + e);
}

int    get_av(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
    return((a + b + c + d + e) / 5);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

C needs things explained to it. It won't make the inferences many languages will. Furthermore the syntax is wrong. Let me enumerate the issues (not all of these are strictly necessary in this circumstance, but you should do them):

1. Declare return types for your functions. `int main()` and for `sumavg` that brings us to number 2.
2. C does not allow for returning multiple values that way. By that syntax, `sm` will be discarded (you're using a comma operator in the `return` statement). You should probably declare `int sum()` and `int avg()` as two separate functions.
3. Declare types for your parameters. `int sum(int n, int w, int o, int b, int h)`
4. Functions should be declared before they are called. You can do this by putting a 'prototype' at the top (the function's signature with the body replaced with a semicolon and parameters potentially unnamed): `int sum(int,int,int,int,int);`
5. Return values are not communicated to the calling function by virtue of having the same name. You need to assign them explicitly, i.e., `sm = sum(a,b,c,d,e);`

Comment: It is perfectly legitimate to use a prototype declaration with names for the arguments: `int sum(int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4, int v5);` would work, as would `int sum(int n, int w, int o, int b, int h);`.

Comment: Your comment doesn't mention "optional"; it says that the prototype must not name the parameters.  If you'd said "and possibly with the parameters unnamed" (or something similar), we'd not be having this discussion.

Comment: Fixed. Should have not been so quick in writing it.

Comment: Good.  I can only up-vote once, though.  Shall we remove these comments?